# error 1045: access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password NO... when connecting through extended classes,others

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class that was connecting to the database without issue. Upon extending that class the same connection fails. The credentials work in phpMyAdmin and command line.

The error I get when attempting to connect to the server:

```
1045: Access denied for user 'phpClasses'@'Jesse-Server' (using password: NO)
```

I have also tried alternate credentials with the same result.

The following is the constructor and property definitions of the parent class and then the child class, then the caller model:

```
//Database.php
private $dbhost;
private $dbname;
private $dbusername;
private $dbuserpassword;
private $dbtableprefix;
private $dbport;
protected $dbC;
public function __construct($ndbhost = "localhost", $ndbname = "", $ndbusername = "", $ndbuserpassword = "", $ndbtableprefix = " ", $ndbport = 3600)
{
$this->dbhost = $ndbhost; // Default = localhost
$this->dbname = $ndbname; // Default = None
$this->dbusername = $ndbusername; //Default = None
$this->dbuserpassword = $ndbuserpassword; // Default = None
$this->dbtableprefix = $ndbtableprefix; //Default = None sets the prefix before the table name so that it can be used with the same db with different tables.
$this->dbport = $ndbport; // Default  = 3600
// starting the connection
@ $this->dbC = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbusername, $this->dbuserpassword, $this->dbname);//, $this->dbport);
if ($this->dbC->connect_error) {
  //catch error connecting.
  die("There was a connection error while attempting to connect to the database " . $this->dbname . " on " . $this->dbhost . ":" . $this->dbport . ". The following is the error that we received back: <strong>" . $this->dbC->connect_errno . ": " . $this->dbC->connect_error . "</strong>\n Please correct this issue, if you need assistance see your database or IT administrator.");
}else{
  //echo "Connected to " . $this->dbname . " on " . $this->dbhost . ":" . $this->dbport;
}
}
```

Now the child

```
//QueryBuilder.php
protected $dbC;
private $host;
private $dbName;
private $dbUser;
private $dbPassword;
private $tablePrefix;
private $dbport;
function __construct($ndbhost = "localhost", $ndbname = "", $ndbusername = "", $ndbuserpassword = "", $ndbtableprefix = " ", $ndbport = 3600){
  //default Constructor
  $this->host = $ndbhost;
  $this->dbName = $ndbname;
  $this->dbUser = $ndbusername;
  $this->dbPassword = $ndbuserpassword;
  $this->tablePrefix = $ndbtableprefix;
  $this->dbport = $ndbport;

  echo $this->host . ',';
  echo $this->dbName . ',';
  echo $this->dbUser . ',';
  echo $this->dbPassword . ',';
  echo $this->tablePrefix . ',';
  echo $this->dbport;

  parent::__construct($this->host, $this->dbName, $this->dbUser, $this->dbpassword, $this->tableprefix, $this->dbport);
  $this->dbC = parent::getdbconnection();
}
```

The model

```
//model.php
require("./Class/Database.php");
require("./Class/QueryBuilder.php");
$result=false;
$host = '192.168.1.2'; //or localhost , same thing, also tried 127.0.0.1
$database = 'phpclasses';
$dbuser = 'phpClasses';
$dbuserpw = 'test1234';
//now I want to see that the connection has been made.
//$db = new DatabaseClass($host, $database, $dbuser, $dbuserpw);
$qb = new QueryBuilderClass($host, $database, $dbuser, $dbuserpw);
```

I thank you all for your time and your help;

Jesse Fender

Comment: Where is the code for `getdbconnection()`? Are you seeing that error 1045 in the php log?

Comment: `192.168.1.2,phpclasses,phpClasses,test1234, ,3600` 
is the printing from the QueryBuilderClass of the values stored in the child class properties

Comment: @mkaatman:: all that does is return by ref the connection to the child class to be used... but here it is:: `protected function getdbconnection(){
    return $this->dbC;
  }`

and i am not sure if it would be displaying in the php log, I think i can find it. let me look and ill get back with you

Comment: Maybe if you remove the error supressor `@` it wil give you more hints on why it fails.

Comment: @mkaatman :: no the error is not in the php error log, and not in any other log in my log files...

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier:: Let me give that a try:: this is what it gave me back--> `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpClasses'@'Jesse-Server' (using password: NO) in ...\www\phpprojects\phpClassPractice\Class\Database.php on line 24`

Comment: You have a typo. You're assigning the password to `$this->dbPassword` but are passing `$this->dbpassword` into the parent constructor. PHP variables are case sensitive. I don't know why you are re-storing all the DB credentials in the child class, or in fact storing them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the child. You've got mixed case typos for $this->dbpassword vs $this->dbPassword. Same with $tablePrefix vs $tableprefix

Comment: Yeah, I recreated his entire example locally to double check what was going on. I felt the need to give him an answer since I went through the trouble. The php error log made the problem very obvious if users would simply use it. I added a close vote for typo anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry - I was stumped at this, My error log didn't have this located.

Comment: @JesseFender chances are you don't have your error reporting set high enough. I suggest you use `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your development environment's `php.ini` file. `display_errors = On` doesn't hurt either

Comment: I'd go through the trouble of getting that log file working. It will speed up troubleshooting immensely.

Comment: @mkaatman Thank you - I will defiantly look into why its not reporting errors into the log.